# Joining a thread started with StartNew()

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

When using the StartNew() method to kick off a process on a new thread, I need to figure out how to make another call into this object in that same thread (I assume this would be some sort of Join operation?).

The following example is dumbed down to illustrate the meat of what I am trying to do.  I am well aware it is severely lacking in basic concurrency considerations.  But I didn't want to cloud the code with all of that logic, so please forgive me on that.

The following console app shows what I am trying to accomplish.  Assume on the StartNew() call a new thread with ID 9976 is created and the method invoked there.  I would like the subsequent call to ProcessImmediate() in the file system watcher change event handler to be made on thread 9976 as well.  As it stands, the call would share the same thread that is used for the file system watcher change event.

Can this be done, and if so, how?

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var runner = new Runner();
            runner.Run();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class Runner
    {
        private Activity _activity = null;
        private FileSystemWatcher _fileSystemWatcher;

        public void Run()
        {
            _activity = new Activity();

            // start activity on a new thread
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => _activity.Go());

            _fileSystemWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
            _fileSystemWatcher.Filter = "*.watcher";
            _fileSystemWatcher.Path = "c:\temp";
            _fileSystemWatcher.Changed += FileSystemWatcher_Changed;
            _fileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        }

        private void FileSystemWatcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            // WANT TO CALL THIS FOR ACTIVITY RUNNING ON PREVIOUSLY CALLED THREAD
            _activity.ProcessImmediate();
        }
    }

    public class Activity
    {
        public void Go()
        {
            while (!Stop)
            {
                // for purposes of this example, magically assume that ProcessImmediate has not been called when this is called
                DoSomethingInteresting();

                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
            }
        }
        protected virtual void DoSomethingInteresting() { }

        public void ProcessImmediate()
        {
            // for purposes of this example, assume that Go is magically in its sleep state when ProcessImmediate is called
            DoSomethingInteresting();
        }

        public bool Stop { get; set; }
    }
}
```

*** UPDATE ***

Thanks for the excellent responses.  I took Mike's suggestion and implemented it for my console app.  Below is the full working code which also includes the use of a cancellation token.  I post this in case someone else might find it useful.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var runner = new Runner();
            runner.Run();
            Console.ReadKey();
            runner.Stop();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class Runner
    {
        private Activity _activity = null;
        private FileSystemWatcher _fileSystemWatcher;
        private CancellationTokenSource _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

        public void Stop() { _cts.Cancel(); }

        public void Run()
        {
            _activity = new Activity();

            // start activity on a new thread
            var task = new Task(() => _activity.Go(_cts.Token), _cts.Token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
            task.Start();

            _fileSystemWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
            _fileSystemWatcher.Filter = "*.watcher";
            _fileSystemWatcher.Path = "C:\\Temp\\FileSystemWatcherPath";
            _fileSystemWatcher.Changed += FileSystemWatcher_Changed;
            _fileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        }

        private void FileSystemWatcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            // WANT TO CALL THIS FOR ACTIVITY RUNNING ON PREVIOUSLY CALLED THREAD
            _activity.ProcessImmediate();
        }
    }

    public class Activity : IDisposable
    {
        private AutoResetEvent _processing = new AutoResetEvent(false);

        public void Go(CancellationToken ct)
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "Go";

            while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                // for purposes of this example, magically assume that ProcessImmediate has not been called when this is called
                DoSomethingInteresting();
                _processing.WaitOne(5000);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Exiting");
        }
        protected virtual void DoSomethingInteresting()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Doing Something Interesting on thread {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId));
        }

        public void ProcessImmediate()
        {
            // for purposes of this example, assume that Go is magically in its sleep state when ProcessImmediate is called
            _processing.Set();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (_processing != null)
            {
                _processing.Dispose();
                _processing = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should use `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` if you are creating a task that will not complete quickly. Second, use an `AutoResetEvent` to signal the waiting thread to wake up. Note that below `ProcessImmediate` will return before `DoSomethingInteresting` has completed running on the other thread. Example:

```
using System.Threading;

public class Activity : IDisposable
{
    private AutoResetEvent _processing = new AutoResetEvent(false); 

    public void Go()
    {
        while (!Stop)
        {
            // for purposes of this example, magically assume that ProcessImmediate has not been called when this is called
            DoSomethingInteresting();

            _processing.WaitOne(2000);
        }
    }
    protected virtual void DoSomethingInteresting() { }

    public void ProcessImmediate()
    {
        _processing.Set();
    }

    public bool Stop { get; set; }

    public void Dispose() 
    {
        if (_processing != null)
        {
            _processing.Dispose();
            _processing = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How would the FileSystemWatcher_Changed method be altered to ensure that the ProcessImmediate call happens on the same thread as Go?

Comment: @John I'm not sure I understand what you want. The content of `ProcessImmediate` has moved onto the other thread. Do you have something else in `ProcessImmediate` that you want invoked on the other thread?

Comment: Never mind, yes, your example does exactly what I was looking for.  I have updated my question with the final console code in case someone else has a similar question.

Answer (score 1):

User mike has given a better solution, which will be appropriate when you like to call the same method immediately. If you want to call a different methods immediately I'll expand mike's answer to achieve that.

```
using System.Threading;

public class Activity : IDisposable
{
    private AutoResetEvent _processing = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    private ConcurrentQueue<Action> actionsToProcess = new ConcurrentQueue<Action>();

    public void Go()
    {
        while (!Stop)
        {
            // for purposes of this example, magically assume that ProcessImmediate has not been called when this is called
            DoSomethingInteresting();

            _processing.WaitOne(2000);
             while(!actionsToProcess.IsEmpty)
             {
                 Action action;
                 if(actionsToProcess.TryDeque(out action))
                     action();
             }
        }
    }
    protected virtual void DoSomethingInteresting() { }

    public void ProcessImmediate(Action action)
    {
        actionsToProcess.Enqueue(action);
        _processing.Set();
    }

    public bool Stop { get; set; }

    public void Dispose() 
    {
        if (_processing != null)
        {
            _processing.Dispose();
            _processing = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're using mike's code, no need to modify anything. that should work

Answer (score 0):

To execute different methods on the same thread you can use a message loop that dispatches incoming requests. A simple option would be to use the [event loop scheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.concurrency.eventloopscheduler%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) of the Reactive Extensions and to "recursively" schedule your Go() function - if in the mean time a different operation is scheduled it would be processed before the next Go() operation.

Here is a sample:

```
class Loop
    : IDisposable
{
    IScheduler scheduler = new EventLoopScheduler();
    MultipleAssignmentDisposable stopper = new MultipleAssignmentDisposable();

    public Loop()
    {
        Next();
    }

    void Next()
    {
        if (!stopper.IsDisposed)
            stopper.Disposable = scheduler.Schedule(Handler);
    }

    void Handler()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Handler: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        Next();
    }

    public void Notify()
    {
        scheduler.Schedule(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Notify: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        });
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        stopper.Dispose();
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var l = new Loop())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Press 'q' to quit.");
        while (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.Q)
            l.Notify();
    }
}
```

Comment: @John: I tried to show this with the Notify() method: You could queue the call up for execution on the EventLoopThread by calling scheduler.Schedule(DoSomethingInteresting).